# "English" details missing from store listing in SDK

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have an app live in the google workspace marketplace.

When I go to my SDK > [Store Listing](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk_publish?project=) tab, the "English" details for my app is missing.

So I can't edit/udpate the english details for my app.

[screenshot of my store listing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTRou.png)

Anyone know why the english details are missing or where I can edit them?

The English/main listing details used to be in the app configuration tab, but then they were moved to the store listing tab, and now it is missing.

Do I need to add "English" back as a language and copy and paste everything from my live store listing again? I don't want to mess anything up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, I work in the Google Workspace Marketplace. Can you tell me what the app id is (it's at the top of the App Configuration page) so I can take a look, please?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the definition of the app and currently does not have descriptions with the English (en) locale. The current English text is under the Finnish (fi) locale.

To change it just expand the Finnish description and change the language to English, leaving the same text.